I want to import RareLabelEncoder from feature_engin
i am trying to import RareLabelEncoder from feature_engine.encoding but it keeps giving me this error summary: ImportError: cannot import name '_get_container_adapter' from 'sklearn.utils._set_output' (C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_set_output.py)
i tried : from feature_engine.encoding, import RareLabelEncoder.
I was expecting that the RareLabelEncoder function will be imported from the feature_engine library
